# Get window size without degrading performance

Tags: wpf, performance

My WPF program sometimes needs the size of the window. The simplest solution is to bind the `ActualWith` and `ActualHight`. But how is the performance when doing so? Is the Height and Width updated repeatedly each time I resize the window?
Is there any way to get the size only when I need it?

Comment: If you want to get the height and width, use the ActualHeight/ActualWidth properties. To answer your last question, you should provide some code (where should we know when you need it^^).

Comment: Did you check out [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? Maybe this question would more appropriately belong there...

Comment: If you "sometimes" need the size, why don't you exactly then get the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` values?

Comment: How do I get ActualWidth and ActualHeidht from View to ViewModel when I need it?

Comment: Is the size of your Window changing that frequently that performance could be a concern here? I can't imagine a scenario where that would be the case...please elaborate on your question.

Comment: You could create one property for each value in your ViewModel and pass the values in your SizeChanged-EventHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, when you are worried about performance: test.

Binding to the ActualHeight and ActualWidth might be not so bad because the Window might not change that much/many times.

The only (proper) way to connect the ViewModel to the View is by using a binding. If this is too costly you could add two extra properties to the Window/View that only update (using a resize event for instance) when this is relevant to you. You could then bind the ViewModel to those.

My bet is that your application contains other things that need more attention ;)